# Shadow-plugin-bitcoin simulator

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I am trying to run the make install command on the shadow-plugin-bitcoin simulator and this is the error that I get. I've been trying to solve it but I can't find the right solution. Please help, thank you.

```
Scanning dependencies of target shadow-bitcoin-bitcode
[  0%] Building LLVM bitcode version.cpp.bc
[  1%] Building LLVM bitcode addrman.cpp.bc
[  1%] Building LLVM bitcode alert.cpp.bc
[  1%] Building LLVM bitcode base58.cpp.bc
[  2%] Building LLVM bitcode allocators.cpp.bc
[  2%] Building LLVM bitcode bloom.cpp.bc
[  2%] Building LLVM bitcode chainparams.cpp.bc
[  3%] Building LLVM bitcode checkpoints.cpp.bc
[  3%] Building LLVM bitcode coins.cpp.bc
[  4%] Building LLVM bitcode core.cpp.bc
[  4%] Building LLVM bitcode crypter.cpp.bc
[  4%] Building LLVM bitcode hash.cpp.bc
[  5%] Building LLVM bitcode init.cpp.bc
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:563:9: error: reference to 'int64_t' is ambiguous
        int64_t n = 0;
        ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:197:1: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'int64_t'
__intN_t (64, __DI__);
^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:188:15: note: expanded from macro '__intN_t'
  typedef int int##N##_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (MODE)))
              ^
<scratch space>:126:1: note: expanded from here
int64_t
^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/boost_1_50_0/boost/cstdint.hpp:308:50: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'boost::int64_t'
     typedef  ::boost::long_long_type            int64_t;
                                                 ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:564:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
        if (ParseMoney(mapArgs["-mintxfee"], n) && n > 0)
                                             ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:564:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
        if (ParseMoney(mapArgs["-mintxfee"], n) && n > 0)
                                                   ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:565:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
            CTransaction::nMinTxFee = n;
                                      ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:571:9: error: reference to 'int64_t' is ambiguous
        int64_t n = 0;
        ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:197:1: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'int64_t'
__intN_t (64, __DI__);
^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:188:15: note: expanded from macro '__intN_t'
  typedef int int##N##_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (MODE)))
              ^
<scratch space>:126:1: note: expanded from here
int64_t
^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/boost_1_50_0/boost/cstdint.hpp:308:50: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'boost::int64_t'
     typedef  ::boost::long_long_type            int64_t;
                                                 ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:572:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
        if (ParseMoney(mapArgs["-minrelaytxfee"], n) && n > 0)
                                                  ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:572:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
        if (ParseMoney(mapArgs["-minrelaytxfee"], n) && n > 0)
                                                        ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:573:44: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
            CTransaction::nMinRelayTxFee = n;
                                           ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:627:5: error: reference to 'int64_t' is ambiguous
    int64_t nStart;
    ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:197:1: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'int64_t'
__intN_t (64, __DI__);
^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:188:15: note: expanded from macro '__intN_t'
  typedef int int##N##_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (MODE)))
              ^
<scratch space>:126:1: note: expanded from here
int64_t
^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/boost_1_50_0/boost/cstdint.hpp:308:50: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'boost::int64_t'
     typedef  ::boost::long_long_type            int64_t;
                                                 ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:826:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nStart'
        nStart = GetTimeMillis();
        ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:905:58: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nStart'
    LogPrintf(" block index %15dms\n", GetTimeMillis() - nStart);
                                                         ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/util.h:117:39: note: expanded from macro 'LogPrintf'
#define LogPrintf(...) LogPrint(NULL, __VA_ARGS__)
                                      ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:1065:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nStart'
    nStart = GetTimeMillis();
    ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/init.cpp:1074:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nStart'
           addrman.size(), GetTimeMillis() - nStart);
                                             ^
/home/smthethwa/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/build/bitcoin/src/util.h:117:39: note: expanded from macro 'LogPrintf'
#define LogPrintf(...) LogPrint(NULL, __VA_ARGS__)
                                      ^
13 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [src/init.cpp.bc] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/shadow-bitcoin-bitcode.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't helpful and I'm months late but I think there's a missing dependency issue going on here based on the fact that you keep getting a typedef error

```
typedef  ::boost::long_long_type            int64_t;
```

[I recall reading an issue with the Boost library that you have to manually patch a file for boost 1.50, so this may be what that is referring to.](https://github.com/shadow/shadow-plugin-bitcoin/wiki#boost)

Specifically down the rabbit hole of links, here is the patch for `trunk/boost/cstdint.hpp`:

```
Index: trunk/boost/cstdint.hpp
===================================================================
--- a/trunk/boost/cstdint.hpp
+++ b/trunk/boost/cstdint.hpp
@@ -42,5 +42,8 @@
 // See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3548 and 
http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10990
//
-#if defined(BOOST_HAS_STDINT_H) && (!defined(__GLIBC__) || defined(__GLIBC_HAVE_LONG_LONG))
+#if defined(BOOST_HAS_STDINT_H)                                 \
+  && (!defined(__GLIBC__)                                       \
+      || defined(__GLIBC_HAVE_LONG_LONG)                        \
+      || (defined(__GLIBC__) && ((__GLIBC__ > 2) || ((__GLIBC__ == 2) && (__GLIBC_MINOR__ >= 17)))))

 // The following #include is an implementation artifact; not part of interface.
```